# Issue with using $_GET['id'] to get ID from route (Angular Site)

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-routing

I have an error where it will not send the id into the page with $_GET['id'] (#/post?id=1)

I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\ls\includes\post.php on line 3
```

I have a blog page. List blogs posts works fine.

The issue is when I try to send the id to my posts page:

Blog.php

```
<?php
require_once("../admin/phpscripts/init.php");
$tbl="tbl_blog";
$getPosts = getAll($tbl);
//echo $getPosts;
?>
<section id="blog">
<h2 class="hidden">Blog Posts</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"><h2>Blog</h2></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"><h3>My thoughts, beliefs and complaints.</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="blog-posts">
<?php
if(!is_string($getPosts)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getPosts)){
        echo "<h1>{$row['b_title']}</h1>";
        echo "<span>Posted: {$row['b_date']} by {$row['b_author']}</span><br><br>";
        echo "<a href=\"#/post?id={$row['b_id']}\">Read Post...</a><br><br>";
        }
        } else {
        //echo "nope...";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Post.php

```
<?php
require_once("../admin/phpscripts/init.php");
echo $_GET["id"];   
echo "hello";
?>
```

Read.php (Called in init.php with require_once)

```
<?php
function getAll($tbl){
    require_once("config.php");
    $queryAll = "SELECT * FROM {$tbl}";
    //echo $queryAll;
    $runAll = mysqli_query($link, $queryAll);
    if($runAll) {
        return $runAll;
    } else {
        $error = "There was an error accessing this information. Shoot me an email at me@lstew.com";
        return $error;
    }

    mysqli_close($link); //want to make sure that it is terminated, do not want anything accessible
} 


function getPost($id, $tbl, $col) {
    require_once("config.php");
    $querySingle = "SELECT * FROM {$tbl} WHERE {$col}={$id}";
    //echo $querySingle;
    $runSingle = mysqli_query($link, $querySingle);
    if($runSingle) {
        return $runSingle;
    }
    else {
        $error = "This is not the movie you are looking for...";
        return $error;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are loading post.php and expecting it to parse (as if loaded via apache or other server) you're gonna have a bad time. You can still use your post.php as a web service. Make an $http (ajax) call to it rather than trying load load a PHP script client side. Display what $http returns in your html templates

Comment: @Ronnie any chance you could show me how that is done? I'm new to angular all this. Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you done any ajax before?

Comment: I won't fix it, but I can show you an example. Give me a few mins. In the meantime, please start reading this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @Ronnie Okay will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is make an `$http` request or ajax request when communicating with server side scripts like PHP.

Angular is client side and will NOT parse PHP files. You can use `$_GET` if you like and make a request like

`$http.get('http://some.url?id=someId')` or I recommend using `$_POST`

```
var params = {id:someId};
$http.post('http://some.url',params);
```

That is how to make an HTTP request on the top level. You need to know when PHP returns something so let's listen for that.

```
var params = {id:someId};
$http.post('http://some.url',params).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

You will see in your console what your php script has returned and at that point you can do what you want with the data in your angular app. See this codepen for an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRYVBB?editors=1010

Since the PHP isn't on codepen and it is on my server, here is what it looks like.

`ang-ajax-demo.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo "Blog data for id: " . $_GET['id'];
} else {
  echo "no id";
}
```

I HIGHLY recommend you rethink how you've done your app. Get rid of all the php files and use html files as our templates. You want your client side and server side files decoupled. Your angular app will make HTTP (ajax) requests to your PHP files.

Comment: I still am having a hard time grasping the concept. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Well, if you haven't done ajax before then I can see you having a hard time with it. While this tutorial is a little outdated, it is still relevant: http://angularcode.com/simple-task-manager-application-using-angularjs-php-mysql/ Take a break from your project and run through this one real quick. It will give you a better understanding of AJAX and what you are trying to do in your app

Comment: Could you explain this part further:  vm = this;
  vm.getPost = function() {
   var randomId = Math.round(Math.random() * 1234);

   $http.get('http://ronnieswietek.com/ang-ajax-demo.php?id=' + randomId).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response.data);
      vm.responseFromServer = response.data;
    });
  } How do go about changing it to the ID from the specific blog item from the db?

Comment: `var randomID = Math.round(Math.random() * 1234);` is for example purposes. You would pass the ID of the actual blog you are interested in getting from the database

Comment: Run through the tutorial link I posted. It will make things more clear for you.

Comment: Good to hear, keep it up!